# Saving and loading high scores in Unity2d

Tags: c#, android, unity3d-2dtools

What I've done so far is set a score to increase by each second in gameplay, get the score to show within the game scene and then set the highscore to be equal to the score if the score is greater than the highscore. This is my code so far:

```
bool gameOver;
    public Text scoreText;
    public Text highScoreText;
    int score;
    int highScore;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        score = 0;
        highScore = 0;
        InvokeRepeating ("scoreUpdate", 1.0f, 1.0f);
        gameOver = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        scoreText.text = "★" + score;
        highScoreText.text = "★" + highScore; 
    }

    public void gameOverActivated() {
        gameOver = true; 
        if (score > highScore) {
            highScore = score; 
        }
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", score);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();

        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highScore", highScore);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }

void scoreUpdate() {
    if (!gameOver) {
        score += 1;

        }} }
```

"game over" is equal to true when this code happens:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D col) {

        if (col.gameObject.tag == "enemyPlanet") {

            ui.gameOverActivated ();
            Destroy (gameObject);
            Application.LoadLevel ("gameOverScene2");
        }

    }
```

What I want is at this point (when the objects collide and game over is true) for the score to be saved, then the game over scene is loaded. How do I save the score at game over, then load it in the game over scene along with a saved highscore??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can do this, two of the most obvious ways to do it if you are only persisting the score for that session is to store it in a **Static Class** or a **Singleton**. These classes will persist for however long you need them to, regardless of scene loading, so be careful how you manage the information in them.

One example of a static class implementation would be:

```
public static class HighScoreManager
{
    public static int HighScore { get; private set; }

    public static void UpdateHighScore(int value)
    {
        HighScore = value;
    }
}
```

If you are looking to persist the data for a longer amount of time you will need to look at [this](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/persistence-data-saving-loading)

I hope this helps!